# How to deal with increasing loss and low validation accuracy in training with VGGNet?

Tags: conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I am trying to create a model to predict the art style of painting. To do so I am using the dataset that Kaggle provides for their competition named Painter by Numbers. Though there are 137 art styles in the dataset I am using only three of them. Those three styles are namely - Impressionism, Expressionism, and Surrealism. I have taken 3000 images from each class to train the model. Moreover, I have used 300 images from each class totaling 900 images to validate the training. 
I have planned to use pre-trained VGGNet as the bottom layer of my model. I have trained the model on Google Colab. Now the issue is, as the model started to learn the loss is ever increasing and validation accuracy is near .33 which is not pleasant. Random guessing will also give this accuracy.

I created a model with a base layer of pre-trained VGGNet. I added some fully connected layers with 1024 neurons in the first two layers, 512 neurons in the third layer and 3 neurons in the last layer. Optimizer I used was SGD with a learning rate of 0.01, decay 1e-6, momentum 0.9. My loss function is "categorical_crossentropy". Moreover, the input image shape was (100,100,3). 
For training, I declared samples per epoch as 100. The number of the epoch was 30. Below I have provided all the codes.

```
model_vgg16_conv = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

input = Input(shape=(100,100,3), name='image_input')
output_vgg16_conv = model_vgg16_conv(input)

x = Flatten(name='flatten')(output_vgg16_conv) 
x = Dense( 1024, activation='relu', name='fc1')(x) 
x = Dense( 1024, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
x = Dense(  512, activation='relu', name='fc3')(x)
x = Dense(    3, activation='softmax', name='predictions')(x)

my_model = Model(input=input, output=x)

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

my_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.1, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_root, target_size=(100,100), batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical')
test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_root, target_size=(100,100), batch_size=32, class_mode='categorical')

my_model.fit_generator(training_set, samples_per_epoch=100, nb_epoch=30, validation_data=test_set, nb_val_samples=300)
```

This generates low validation accuracy and ever-increasing loss value. Even the loss value is raised to 10. And moreover, this produces a low validation accuracy. What to do to get the situation better?